# I'm trying to add a slide-show to my html but the next and previous buttons are not working

Tags: javascript, html

Html

```
<div class="slideshow">
          <a href="Updates/11_Oct_2023.html"><img src="Updates/11_Oct_2023.JPG"></a>
          <a href="Updates/11_Oct_2023.html"><img src="Updates/11_Oct_2023.JPG"></a>
          <a href="link3.html"><img src="image3.jpg"></a>
        </div>

       <button id="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">Prev</button>
       <button id="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">Next</button>
```

It throws
`Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: plusSlides is not defined at onclick (c:\Users\prima\Downloads\technoclub-uoh.github.io\index.html:71:50)`

Js

```
<script>
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

It throws
`Unexpected token '<'`

I've rechecked several times and I believe I have defined plusSlides in my js code. I'm stuck at figuring out what is wrong with the js code.

Comment: Please explain `showSlides(slideIndex += n);`

Comment: Typo?  The latter error suggests that you put HTML code in a JavaScript file.  If your second code snippet is meant to indicate the contents of a JavaScript file, remove the `<script>` element and just use JavaScript code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cansuk/pe3h0Lub/1/ 
I pasted your code to jsfiddle.
There seems no error.